# How to acces to the B,G,R of an image with opencv in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, pixel

I would like to access to all R,G,B channels of my image, I wrote some code but it gives me just the R,G,B of one pixel even if I did an append...

I'm a beginner with Python so can you help me please?

Here's the code :

```
#coding: utf8
import numpy as np
import cv2
from imageio import imread

imgcolor = imread("/home/PATH/bougieHaut3.jpg")
rows,cols,rgb = imgcolor.shape
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range (cols):
        blue = imgcolor[i,j,0]
        B=[]
        B.append(blue)
        green = imgcolor[i,j,1]
        G=[]
        G.append(green)
        red = imgcolor[i,j,2]
        R=[]
        R.append(red)
print(B,G,R)
```

Thank you so much for your help :) !

Comment: The problem is that you recreates the variables B, G and R in each loop. It should work if you move B=[], G=[] and R=[] before the for loops

Comment: In python -> avoid loops, use numpy.... just use `B = imgcolor[:,:,0]` and if you just want the 1D array `B = imgcolor[:,:,0].ravel()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating the R/G/B lists for each pixel, so they will end up containing only one entry.

Try

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from imageio import imread

imgcolor = imread("/home/PATH/bougieHaut3.jpg")
rows, cols, rgb = imgcolor.shape
R = []
G = []
B = []
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        B.append(imgcolor[i, j, 0])
        G.append(imgcolor[i, j, 1])
        R.append(imgcolor[i, j, 2])
print(B, G, R)
```

**EDIT**: A faster way to do this, using Numpy's slicing, is

```py
imgcolor = imread("/home/PATH/bougieHaut3.jpg")
B = imgcolor[:,:,0].flatten()
G = imgcolor[:,:,1].flatten()
R = imgcolor[:,:,2].flatten()
```

without a loop – you could then use `list()` to cast those Numpy arrays into lists if you need to.

Comment: @SabrinaMEHLAL You're welcome! I edited in a faster version of the same idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the invariant functions like:
import PIL
import math

```
def invariant_r(img):
  c1 = np.zeros((img_height, img_weight))
  for i in range(0, img_height):
    for j in range(0, img_weight):
      b = img[i,j,0]
      g = img[i,j,1]
      r = img[i,j,2]
      x = (r/max(g,b))
      c1[i][j]= math.atan(x)
  return c1

def invariant_g(img):
  c1 = np.zeros((img_height, img_weight))
  for i in range(0, img_height):
    for j in range(0, img_weight):
      b = img[i,j,0]
      g = img[i,j,1]
      r = img[i,j,2]
      x = (g/max(r,b))
      c1[i][j]= math.atan(x)
  return c1

def invariant_b(img):
  c1 = np.zeros((img_height, img_weight))
  for i in range(0, img_height):
    for j in range(0, img_weight):
      b = img[i,j,0]
      g = img[i,j,1]
      r = img[i,j,2]
      x = (b/max(r,g))
      c1[i][j]= math.atan(x)
  return c1
```

And call them like:

```
 r_img = invariant_r(img)
  g_img = invariant_g(img)
  b_img = invariant_b(img)
```

After merging these values in an array, you have color invariant array.